# Getting UserId from MVC using WebMetrix

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I'm using bellow login method to login in a MVC 5 application.
What I want to do is get the id of the user that is currently logged.
I tried to use these 2 methods:

// 1

// This one raise an exception:

```
Guid loggedUser = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
```

> Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.

// 2

// sets loggedUser variable to null

```
loggedUser = User.Identity.GetUserId();
```

// Login Method within Controller

```
 public ActionResult Login(Login logindata, string ReturnUrl)
                    {
                    if (ModelState.IsValid)
                        {
                        if (WebSecurity.Login(logindata.Username, logindata.Password))
                            {
                            if (ReturnUrl != null)
                                {
                                return Redirect(ReturnUrl);
                                }
                            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                            }
                        }
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "Sorry the username or password is invalid ");
                    return View(logindata);
                    }
```

My question is what I'm doing wrong and if it's possible to get the logged user id like this???

Thanks

Comment: I also tried this in the respective View: @HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId()                                              returns null...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used this method and worked:

```
WebSecurity.GetUserId("loggedUser")
```